# Remove white space from all Xml Node Values

Tags: c#, xml

Is there anyway to trim leading and trailing white spaces from XML node values without looping through each node.

For instance `<someElement> value here </someElement>` would become `<someElement>value here</someElement>`

The following code does this but I don't want to loop through each node which would be a performance hit:

```
if (node.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
  node.InnerText = node.InnerText.Trim();
else
{
  for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
  {
    TrimLeadingOrTrailingSpacesFromNodeValue(node.ChildNodes[i]);
  }
}
```

Is there a better way?  The `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace` is not what I am looking for, I need to trim the values in the XML nodes.

Comment: well you could use linq to xml but esentially it does looping as well so not much preformance increase. The answer is allready described in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851247/linq-to-xml-xelement-remove-leaves-unwanted-whitespace

Comment: I wouldn't of said the performance hit would be a concern unless you were handling large throughput. Not having the functionality in your own code would be the main gain since you wouldn't have to maintain it. (I also don't understand why this question has been down-voted)

Answer (score 5):

Here is an extension I wrote for `Xml.Linq.XElement` but I am not sure about performance.

I did find this [performance comparison of XmlDocument vs XElement when creating xml](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codejunkie/archive/2008/10/08/xmldocument-vs-xelement-performance.aspx) documents that shows 6x - 10x improvement using XElement.  I am not sure how valid those results are AND it is creating a document vs. iterating over elements and updating values so take it for what it's worth.

Either way, thought I would share an alternative.  Maybe later myself or someone else will have motivation to analyze the performance of this particular usage (removing whitespace).

```
  public static class XElementExtensions
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Trims whitespace from the xml node values.  
    /// DOES NOT trim whitespace outside of values, can use PreserveWhitespace LoadOption when parsing for that.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element"></param>
    public static void TrimWhiteSpaceFromValues(this XElement element)
    {
      foreach (var descendent in element.Descendants())
      {
        if (!descendent.HasElements)
        {
          descendent.SetValue(descendent.Value.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
          descendent.TrimWhiteSpaceFromValues();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Example Usage:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(xmlDocString);
element.TrimWhiteSpaceFromValues();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `XMLDocument` then you could try:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.preserveWhitespace = false;
xmlDocument.load("my_document.xml");
```

As shown here: [How to remove whitespace from an XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231374/how-to-remove-whitespace-from-an-xmldocument)

Comment: As stated in a comment under the answer you duplicated, this only works if you re-save the document before accessing it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It was still a point in the right direction was it not? This might be the solution that the user is after...

Comment: I believe he was talking about removing white space from each element value.  For instance `<someElement> value here </someElement>` would become `<someElement>value here</someElement>`

Comment: This does not work for me, even after saving to a MemoryStream and reloading.