# Trim White Spaces from all XML Values

Tags: c#, xml

Can anyone please help me on how to remove all the white spaces from XML values as shown below:

```xml
<organization>
  <Department>
    <Name>IT</Name>
    <Location> Australia </Location>
  </Department>
</organization>
```

To:

```
<organization>
  <Department>
    <Name>IT</Name>
    <Location>Australia</Location>
  </Department>
</organization>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231374/how-to-remove-whitespace-from-an-xmldocument

Comment: so you don't want to remove whitespaces from "XML Document". You want to trim leading whitespaces from "XML Values". iterate and `Trim()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove white space from all Xml Node Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158472/remove-white-space-from-all-xml-node-values). Also, what have you really tried to do, it's not present to us what you *are actually stuck on*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe you want to trim the whitespaces in values. In this scenario, you could select all the leaf nodes using [`Linq to Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) and use [`String.Trim(`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8) to delete all leading and trailing whitespaces

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var nodes = xDoc.Descendants().Where(x=>!x.Elements().Any()); // Select all leaf nodes
foreach(var node in nodes)
{
    node.Value = node.Value.Trim(); // Remove leading and trailing whitespaces
}

var result = xDoc.ToString();
```

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8BlwhT)

Comment: OP hasn't shown an attempt at answering their question, how does this code align with what the *op has tried*, it simply doesn't that we know of. With this in mind, more than likely answer's will be opinionated. A quick search on SO yields great examples the OP could have already used before asking; maybe you could have pointed the OP to an already provided example here instead of having duplicates. Just my thoughts :)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I agree with you and accept the downvote. Thank you for mentioning the reason for downvote.